# Target sum (leetcode 494) - Why one code gives TLE but other don't using python dictionary?

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I recently came across this leetcode question [Target Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/) which i tried to solve using recursion + memoization in Python. But following code gave TLE:

```
class Solution:
def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    
    n=len(nums)
    dp={}
    
    def ftsw(i,t):
        if i==len(nums):
            if t==target:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
            
        if dp.get((i,t)):
            return dp.get((i,t))
        
        dp[(i,t)] = ftsw(i+1,t+nums[i])+ ftsw(i+1,t-nums[i])
        return dp[(i,t)]
    
    
    return(ftsw(0,0))
```

But This code didn't:

```
class Solution:
def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    
    n=len(nums)
    dp={}
    
    def ftsw(i,t):
        if i==len(nums):
            if t==target:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
            
        if (i,t) in dp:
            return dp[(i,t)] 
        
        dp[(i,t)] =  ftsw(i+1,t+nums[i])+ ftsw(i+1,t-nums[i])
        return dp[(i,t)]

        
    
    
    return(ftsw(0,0))
```

can anyone explain why this happened and how python dictionary take these 2 codes differently?

Answer (score 0):

get is a dictionary attribute, so with `dp.get((i,t))`, there's an attribute lookup cost, but for `in` or `dp[(i,t)]`, no attribute lookup is required and fields can be looked for directly in memory.

You can also timeit to see clearly:

```
import timeit

def dp_get(dp):
    if dp.get('a'):
        return dp.get('a')
def dp_in(dp):
    if 'a' in dp:
        return dp['a']

print("dp_get = ",timeit.timeit('dp_get({"a":1, "b":2})',number=100000,setup='from __main__ import dp_get'))
print("dp_in = ",timeit.timeit('dp_in({"a":1, "b":2})',number=100000,setup='from __main__ import dp_in'))
```

Output:

```
dp_get = 0.18514581501949579
dp_in = 0.10382004908751696
```